# Why isn't this boolean changing when it matches my regex?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, boolean

so I am running this in the most recent build of Eclipse. and for some reason, neither me nor my teacher can figure out why this boolean is not changing

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ6u5.png)

```
String value = null;
boolean matching = false;
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]$";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
value = input.next();

if (value.matches(regex))
{
    matching = true;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Name is incorrect, please try again");
}


System.out.println(matching);
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code within the question *as text*, instead of a link to an image

Comment: Let's work backwards, why should it change?

Comment: Inputting the name Scott should match the regex, yet for some reason it's not.

Comment: Why do you think it should match the regex?

Comment: It should change because the name input into value "Scott" matches the regex pattern of a-zA-z

Comment: @MountainBeast `^` matches the beginning and `$` matches the end, and you only specify one character in between matching `[a-zA-z]`. To have it match more than one character that matches do `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: You are matching a **single** letter and it troubles me that your teacher is reportedly clueless.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the regex ^[a-zA-Z]$, you are matching single letter inputs (for eg. "a", "d" "F") ... since you input multicharacter string, it wouldn't match

In order to match strings of length>=1 you could use the + operator in regexes, like so,

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```